# ng-grid embeded menu is being hidden

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-grid

We are currently using `ng-grid` to display our data in a grid. However, what we are now looking to do is to create a menu for each row.

An easy task if it was in a normal table. However, using an `ng-grid`, we are having issues as the actual menu is not displayed.

In other words, it's placing the menu within the cell, and so when its displayed, as the overflow is hidden on the cell, we can only see part of the menu (hope that makes sense)

We are trying to achieve something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/akA6H/39/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.name = 'Superhero';
}

myApp.directive('showOnRowHover',

function () {
   return {
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.closest('tr').bind('mouseenter', function () {
            element.show();
        });
        element.closest('tr').bind('mouseleave', function () {
            element.hide();

            var contextmenu = element.find('#contextmenu');
            contextmenu.click();

            element.parent().removeClass('open');
        });
     }
  };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cell-template like this:

```
    $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{
        field: 'name',
        displayName: 'Name'
      },
      {
        field: 'age',
        displayName: 'Age',
        cellTemplate: '<div ng-mouseover="showmenu=true" ng-mouseleave="showmenu=false" class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}' +
          '<span class="hmenu" ng-show="showmenu" ng-click=sayHello(row.entity.name)><button>click me</button></span>' +
          '</div>'
      }
    ]
    };
```

Look at this simplified [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Uxo8ONZ1C14doGY1eyf?p=preview)

**UPDATE:**
Uh, I forgot: If you want to have this on row hover, you need to define a row-template too and put the switch there and apply the value to the $parent.

```
    $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    rowTemplate: '<div  ng-mouseover="$parent.showmenu=true" ng-mouseleave="$parent.showmenu=false" ng-style="{\'cursor\': row.cursor, \'z-index\': col.zIndex() }" ' +
      'ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ' +
      'class="ngCell {{col.cellClass}}" ng-cell></div>',
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'name',
      displayName: 'Name'
    }, {
      field: 'age',
      displayName: 'Age',
      cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}' +
        '<span class="hmenu" ng-show="showmenu" ng-click=sayHello(row.entity.name)><button>click me</button></span>' +
        '</div>'
    }]
    };
```

[Updated Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OQodl2CHtyiNeHiqJN4H?p=preview)

Comment: not really what we are after. Basically, we would like a menu displayed for each row. i.e. we have a button on each row, that when a user clicks, they are presented with additional options such as view more details, edit details, delete details etc etc